# Get not hidden fields in PyQGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I try to get a list of all fields - only they one which are not hidden - from QqsVectorLayer in QGIS 3 using python API. In QGIS 2 I used to do it like that:

```
conf = layer.editFormConfig()
for field in layer.fields():
    if conf.widgetType(field.name()) != 'Hidden':
        print(field.alias())
```

What's the proper way to do that in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for index in layer.attributeList():
    if layer.editorWidgetSetup(index).type() != 'Hidden':
        print(layer.attributeDisplayName(index))
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way to get (in addition to the alias or displayName) the field name from the same loop?

Comment: Yeap, you can use `layer.fields()[index].name()` inside that loop.